# Mongoose removes arrays from findByIdAndUpdate (inherited schema)

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to update a Mongoose model using `findByIdAndUpdate`

For the sake of the question, the model is called `ItemVariant` and it inherits from `Item`.

An example of the payload data is:

```
var data = {
  arrayField: [ 1, 3 ],
  description: 'This is a description' }
}
```

If I call

```
ItemVariant.findByIdAndUpdate(objectId, data);
```

I can see that the description gets updated, but the arrayField is not passed to mongo at all - in fact all arrays are removed the data object.

I've been trying to figure out how to do this, looked at setting `$pushAll` for arrays but nothing seems to be working.

Is there something I'm missing here?

The model schema is inherited. The Mongoose model looks like this:

```
function ItemVariantSchema() {
    var self = this;
    Schema.apply(this, arguments);

    self.add({           
        description: [String],
        arrayField: [Number]
    });
}
util.inherits(ItemVariantSchema, ItemSchema);

// the field that represents the sub-class discriminator
var schemaOptions = {
    discriminatorKey: 'type'
};

// create ItemVariant schema
var itemVariantSchema = new ItemVariantSchema({}, schemaOptions);

// create ItemVariant model
Item.discriminator('Variant', itemVariantSchema);

// Export the ItemVariant schema
module.exports = ItemVariantSchema;
```

An example of the mongod --verbose output:

```
command: findAndModify { findandmodify: "itemvariants", query: { _id: ObjectId('5541fb680dc0e9223bea1ddb') }, new: 1, remove: 0, upsert: 0, update: { $set: { description: "EDIT: some description" } } } update: { $set: { description: "EDIT: some description" } } nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 nMatched:1 nModified:0 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:104 reslen:358 0ms
```

As you can see `arrayField` has been removed

I've also tried something like:

```
var data = {
    $set: { description: 'This is a description' },
    $push: { arrayField: [ 1, 3 ] }
}
```

But the $push array seems to be empty by the time it reaches mongo.

Also as suggested by @chridam I have also tried something like:

```
var data = {
    $set: {
        description: 'some description' 
    },
    $addToSet: {
        arrayField: {
            $each: [2, 3]
        }
    }
}
```

and the output now looks like this:

```
command: findAndModify { findandmodify: "itemvariants", query: { _id: ObjectId('5541fb680dc0e9223bea1ddb') }, new: 1, remove: 0, upsert: 0, update: { $set: { description: "EDIT: another description" }, $addToSet: { arrayField: {} } } } update: { $set: { description: "EDIT: another description" }, $addToSet: { arrayField: {} } } nscanned:1 nscannedObjects:1 nMatched:1 nModified:1 keyUpdates:0 numYields:0 locks(micros) w:118 reslen:366 0ms
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the inheritance was the culprit here.

The mongoose model needs to come from the discriminator:

```
var ItemVariant = Item.discriminators['Variant'];
ItemVariant.findByIdAndUpdate(objectId, data);
```

This got it working for me. 
The array clobbering was a bit of red herring. And my question did not paint the whole picture. Thanks for the help @chridam

Answer (score 3):

You need to use the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) operator:

```
var data = {
   "arrayField": [ 1, 3 ],
   "description": "This is a description" 
};

ItemVariant.findByIdAndUpdate(objectId, { "$set": data });
```

-- **UPDATE** --

Try using a combination of the [**`$set`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/set/#up._S_set) update operator on the `description` field and the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) operator with the [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#each-modifier) modifier on the `arrayField` array field. The [**`$each`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#each-modifier) modifier allows the [**`$addToSet`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/addToSet/#up._S_addToSet) operator to add multiple values to the array field:

```
var data = {
   "arrayField": [ 1, 3 ],
   "description": "This is a description" 
};

var update = {
    "$set": {
        "description": data.description
    },
    "$addToSet": {
        "arrayField": {
            "$each": data.arrayField
        }
    }
};

ItemVariant.findByIdAndUpdate(objectId, update, options, callback);
```

Comment: Thanks unfortunately this has the same effect as just passing in ```data``` on its own. Mongoose seems to be clobbering any arrays in the input. Even when I split arrays and add them to the ```$push``` operator.

Comment: @Adamski I've updated my answer with another approach that you could try.

Comment: Updated question - with your new suggestion it seems to send ```arrayField ``` as empty object